# android java.lang.IllegalStateException MediaPlayer.isPlaying

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I published my app and on some phones like Galaxy Nexus or HTC Explorer where my APP crashes.

I tested on many phones and app worked perfectly.

Can you explain me why is this happening and how to fix it ?

**ERROR**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
at com.mario.kvizoman.SoloIgra.novopitanjce(SoloIgra.java:922)
at com.mario.kvizoman.SoloIgra.onClick(SoloIgra.java:901)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3768)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**CODE**

```
if(reptimer!=null) {
    if(reptimer.isPlaying()) {
        reptimer.stop();
    }
}
```

onCreate reptimer is

```
reptimer = MediaPlayer.create(SoloIgra.this, R.raw.napeto);
```

Answer (score 13):

According to the Android documentation: "IllegalStateException if the internal player engine has not been initialized or has been released."

So ensure your MediaPlayer is initialized, and you don't use the released one.

Comment: Hello :) how do I ensure if MediaPlayer is initialized? In my code I have `if(mediaPlayer != null) if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) /* do things */`, but I still get the Exception on second `if`.

Comment: @ocramot manually control your player state - e.g. keep the state in local variable or wrap your code with try/catch blocks

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping there was some function already built-in in the MediaPlayer library

Answer (score 6):

From your code, since `repTimer.isPlaying()` is getting invoked, I assume that the `JAVA` `repTimer` object is **not** `NULL`. However, `IllegalStateException` is triggered when the `native` `MediaPlayer` object is `NULL` (Reference: http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/media/jni/android_media_MediaPlayer.cpp#380 ). Hence, there is some mismatch between your `JAVA` states and `native` states.

**P.S:** You may want to check the code prior the position pasted in this question. In some earlier method call, the native object has been destroyed which is not reflected in your `JAVA` object state.