# How to solve MediaPlayer IllegalStateException issue?

Tags: android, media-player

I know there is a lot of questions about this subject, but none of them helped me. I tried ALL but nothing, still getting  IllegalStateException in my logcat and app crashes.

Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.orar.cngcnasaud;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private CustomActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String[] menuItems;


    private static final String TAG = "AudioDemo";
    private static final String isPlaying = "Media is Playing"; 
    private static final String notPlaying = "Media has stopped Playing"; 

    MediaPlayer player;
    Button playerButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_drawer);

        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gc);
        player.setLooping(false); // Set looping

        // Get the button from the view
        playerButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.buttonmp);
        playerButton.setText(R.string.stop_label);
        playerButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

        // Begin playing selected media
        demoPlay();

        // Release media instance to system
        player.release();


        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        _initMenu();
        mDrawerToggle = new CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer);
        mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: " + v);
            if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonmp) {
                playPause();
            }

    }




    private void demoPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        player.pause();
        playerButton.setText(R.string.play_label);
        Toast.makeText(this, notPlaying, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, notPlaying);
}

    private void playPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(player.isPlaying()) {
          demoPause();
        } else {
          demoPlay();
        }   
    }

    private void demoPlay() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        player.start();
        playerButton.setText(R.string.stop_label);
        Toast.makeText(this, isPlaying, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, isPlaying);
}
```

This is not the whole activity, my activity has a sliding menu too, but this is the code for my MediaPlayer .. Thanks a lot !

L.E:

LOGCAT:

```
02-24 19:09:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1323): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 19:09:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1323): java.lang.IllegalStateException
02-24 19:09:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
02-24 19:09:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at com.orar.cngcnasaud.MainActivity.playPause(MainActivity.java:90)
02-24 19:09:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at com.orar.cngcnasaud.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:72)
02-24 19:09:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
02-24 19:09:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
02-24 19:09:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-24 19:09:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-24 19:09:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-24 19:09:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-24 19:09:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 19:09:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-24 19:09:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-24 19:09:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-24 19:09:24.011: E/AndroidRuntime(1323):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please post logcat as well --> need to know at which line it crashes

Comment: 90 and 72 are the lines.. I've edited the first post for the logcat..

Comment: `[SOLVED]` and the solution was?

Comment: Solved by donfuxx .. good now? I don't have 15 rep to give + ..sorry about that !

Comment: @user3348368 Well, with marking as solved I actually meant clicking the check icon next to my answer, not adding "SOLVED" to the title. It doesn't cost you anything ;-)

Answer (score 13):

Here:

```
 if(player.isPlaying()) {
```

You seem to be calling `ìsPlaying()` method while the player has not yet been initialized. In that case this method throws this IllegalStateException.

I think reason is that in your `onCreate` you actually release (!) the MediaPlayer, see:

```
   // Release media instance to system
    player.release();
```

You should better use the **Activity life cycle methods** to manage releasing your MediaPlayer:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gc);
    player.setLooping(false);
    player.start(); 
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: That's it.. it's working, but the only problem is that the song is played when the app is started, not when the button is pressed..so, how do i change it?

Comment: you don't want the sound to be played when app is started? Well, then remove this line from onCreate method: `// Begin playing selected media
        demoPlay();`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like an initialization problem. Although I have not done a ton of research, here is a possible duplicate:

[java.lang.IllegalStateException in MediaPlayer.isplaying() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357036/java-lang-illegalstateexception-in-mediaplayer-isplaying-method)

Here is another duplicate, also pointing to initialization:

[android java.lang.IllegalStateException MediaPlayer.isPlaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730772/android-java-lang-illegalstateexception-mediaplayer-isplaying)

And here is the dev docs on MediaPlayer, stating prior to calling isPlaying() you'll need to initialize the player:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isPlaying()

Answer (score 1):

perfectly answered by donfuxx.

In case you don't want the sound to start on the creation/reload of your activity, then remove the `player.start` in `Onresume();`