# Android mediaplayer won't start after pause

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying make a simple mediaplayer but the pause button doesn't work. When I click on the pause button it stops but when I click on play again it starts at the start again.

I don't know how to make one button where I can play/pause the button.

Code I currently have:

http://pastebin.com/wiDkzw5S

Thanks already!

Comment: you are not giving the time/length in your pause from where it can start again that's why it starts from start again ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to save current position of media player and [restart it later from that position using `seekTo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo(int)).

Something like:

```
int currentPos = 0;
pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            currentPos = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            //change image to play
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPos);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            //again revert image to pause
        }  
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I keep getting: cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method. I fixed the error but when I run the app it gives me a error when I click on pause. I currently have this: http://pastebin.com/A6AJMc6B

Comment: For `currentPos`? You would need to declare `currentPos` as a global variable. @TimJake

Comment: Where do I add that exactly? I keep getting errors :/

Comment: `int currentPos = 0;` should be before `onCreate`. @TimJake

Comment: Thanks fixed that, now when I start the song with my start button and click on pause it stops but when I click on pause again it says unfortunately the app stopped working

Comment: @TimJake what is output in logcat? Please post that in question.

Comment: @TimJake is that full logcat?

Comment: This is the log from the start to the end( till the error) http://pastebin.com/MR51YJ06

Comment: What's line number 54 of MainActivity.java?

Comment: if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {   That's of my stop button

Comment: @TimJake are you sure you haven't used mediaPlayer.release();?

Comment: You can use `if (mediaPlayer!=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying())`

Comment: This is the whole stop button:  Button stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    
     @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
      mediaPlayer.stop();
      mediaPlayer.release();
     }
    } 
    });
 }

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15730932/1777090) @TimJake may be that's issue

Answer (score 0):

This is running test and running code, you may use this for pause and resume the media player.

```
int length=0;  
Button pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
 pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
 if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
         mediaPlayer.pause();
        length=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();    
    } else {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(length);
        mediaPlayer.start();
          }
       }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but I couldn't get it to resume using the methods above.

I discovered my pauseAllSounds() function was pausing all MediaPlayer instances in my sound pool even if they weren't already playing.  When that happened, it caused an error in each instance which wasn't playing which prevented that instance from playing again later.  I discovered this after some time only by happening across the console output for my running process searching for the cause.  It showed line after line of errors, revealing I was trying to pause from an invalid state.

```
// Make sure you test isPlaying() before pausing
public void pause() {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        position = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }
}
```

Once I added the test to only pause if it was already playing, everything worked.